# Html5 drag and drop unicode chessboard

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to do html5 dragndrop on my html5/css chessboard using unicode pieces but have a problem at the moment with it.
On dragging & dropping the whole 'li' element seems to move & on drop this disrupts the board.

This can be seen on the chess WordPress site at:

http://www.buryknightschess.org.uk/play-chess/

(As can be seen I asked for help with this on SitePoint Forums but haven't had a reply to help yet from there).

Possibly I somehow need just to make the unicode chess pieces draggable & not the whole chess square (`<li></li>`).

I shall keep trying to fix this but meanwhile I would greatly appreciate any advice to help with this html5 dragndrop issue. I look forward to helpful replies, many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `<li/>` is being moved (thus rearranging the chess board) is because in your `drop` function is calling `appendChild`:

```
function drop(event) {
    var element = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

    // This changes the DOM
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(element));
    event.stopPropagation();

    return false;
}
```

Instead of moving that actual DOM node, the `drop` function should copy the `innerHTML` of the node that's being dragged.  Here's how the new `drop` would look function:

```
function drop(event) {
    var coordinate = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var element = document.getElementById(coordinate);

    event.target.innerHTML = element.innerHTML; // Moving piece to new cell
    element.innerHTML = ""; // Clearing old cell

    event.stopPropagation(); // Consider using `event.preventDefault` instead

    return false;
}
```

Also, I'd consider using `event.preventDfault` instead of `event.stopPropagation`.  This makes it possible to add new drop listeners to the board or one of its parents.  For example you may want to add a drop listener to the document body to handle the case where a user tries to drag a piece off the board.

As general remark, have you considering using [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) libraries?  You'd be able to support much richer drag/drop interactions such as snap-to-grid movement and delayed starts.  Also, HTML5 drag-and-drop is typically used to allow users to drag files from their OS desktop onto the a web page.  The way your using it is totally fine, it's just a little strange.

Comment: Xavi-Thank you very much for your excellent & detailed answer. I will use your proposals & study them so I can learn more about html5 dragndrop. Maybe jQuery dnd is better overall but as the chessboard is html5 I wanted to try to keep it all 'native' with html5 dnd. I may do another version using jQuery- thanks again for your great reply!